# Material UI Select component throwing javascript console warning

Tags: material-ui

i am using select component with values by setting them using useEffect like below.

```js
useEffect(()=>{
    const {property, properties} = props;
    setProperties(properties); // properties is an array of values 
    ['somevalue1', 'somevalue2']
     setProperty(property)
},[props])
```

but this leads to following javascript warning. i guess this because of race condition where property is set first rather than properties array. any tips to avoid warning?

You have provided an out-of-range value `somevalue1` for the select component.
Consider providing a value that matches one of the available options or ''.
The available values are "".

below is the code for select that i am using.

```js
<Select
    value={property}
    onChange={onChange}
    input={<BootstrapInput />}
    defaultValue=""
>
    {Object.keys(properties).map((key) => (
        <MenuItem key={key} value={key}>
            {key}
        </MenuItem>
    ))}
</Select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why you set state value in useEffect? If you don't have a specific reason, try modifying it like the code below.

```
const [properties, setProperties] = useState(props.properties);
const [preperty, setProperty] useState(props.property)
```

And the code you asked seems to have the potential for infinite repetition.

Comment: Hi, for the initial flow of my page, Yes i am using useState and it is working straight. but i my page has back button functionality where i need to render previous state so all the previous state values comes via props. so i have no option but to use useEffect().
regarding your infinite loop statement , i disagree because useEffect in my code runs only on prop change.